# Django store csv float items in database

Tags: python, django, csv

I have a csv file with data like:

`Company,104.95,102.8,102.6,104.5,104.5,102.75...\n` etc.

I am storing float values like this `prices[1:len(prices)]` in

`models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=10000)`

but after the values are stored, the float values get quotes like `'104.95','102.8','102.6','104.5','104.5','102.75'`

Whereas I want to store the values as floats, not as strings. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert them to floats like so:

```
float_prices = [float(p) for p in prices[1:len(prices)]]
```

That said, `CommaSeparatedIntegerField` will only validate a comma-separated list of **integers**. Neither strings nor floats are valid for that field - so it's odd that you say you are able to save the data you posted.

Comment: That's what I was wondering but it's being saved anyway. If this doesn't work, how should I store it?

Comment: CommaSeparatedIntegerField is working with float values. And float(p) is working fine, thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a CharField instead (with a leading `_`)

```
_float_prices = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
```

and the `@property` decorator with JSON serialization

```
@property
def float_prices(self):
    return json.loads(self._float_prices)

@float_prices.setter
def float_prices(self, li):
    self._float_prices = json.dumps(li)
```

That way, you can set `float_prices` to a list of floats, and the serialization would be done by the property methods autmatically

```
instance.float_prices = [14.5, 5.2, 9.0]
```

would write `'["14.5", "5.2", "9.0"]'` to `_float_prices`.

---

Alternatively, **Django 1.9 with PostgreSQL** has the [new `models.JSONField()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield) that would do the serialization of a `float` list for you.

```
float_prices = models.JSONField(blank=True)
```